# How to access all HTTP Response Headers

Tags: cookies, http-headers, titanium, titanium-mobile, setcookie

I have a simple mobile app in Titanium that I'm using to debug the ability to log into our user system.

At the moment, I cannot seem to see the `Set-Cookie` response header as it's always returned as `null`.

I'm currently using Titanium SDK 1.7.5 (1.8 is horribly broken).

My code is very simple, a text book example of using the HTTPClient:

```
var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
var url = 'https://auth.csu.edu.au/login/login.pl';
var targetURL = 'http://my.csu.edu.au'

loginButton.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    if (username.value != '' && password.value != '')
    {
        loginReq.open('POST', url);

        Ti.API.info('Sending HTTP Request.');

        var params = {
            username: username.value,
            password: password.value,
            url: targetURL
        }

        loginReq.send(params);
    }
    else {
        alert("Username/Password are required");
    }
});

loginReq.onload = function() {
    var cookie = loginReq.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
    Ti.API.info('Response Status: ' + loginReq.status);
    Ti.API.info('Response Header - Cookie: ' + cookie);
    Ti.API.info('Response Header - Location: ' + loginReq.getLocation());

    if (Ti.Platform.osname !== 'android')
        Ti.API.info('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(loginReq.getResponseHeaders()));

    var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'test.html');
    f.write(this.responseText);

    var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView();
    webview.url = f.nativePath;

    var newWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    newWindow.add(webview);
    newWindow.open({modal:true});
};
```

The output is as follows:

```
[INFO] Sending HTTP Request.
[INFO] Response Status: 200
[INFO] Response Header - Cookie: null
[INFO] Response Header - Location: https://auth.csu.edu.au/login/login.pl?redirect=true&url=http%3a%2f%2fmy%2ecsu%2eedu%2eau
[INFO] Headers: {"Connection":"Keep-Alive","Transfer-Encoding":"Identity","Keep-Alive":"timeout=5, max=99","Content-Type":"text/html","Server":"Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.7d mod_apreq2-20051231/2.6.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.8.4","Date":"Thu, 02 Feb 2012 01:45:29 GMT"}
```

I'm just going around and around in circles as I can't seem to see what is exactly wrong here. What confuses me is that `HTTPClient.getResponseHeaders()` is not even documented ([Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object.html](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object.html)) - and doesn't work for Android.

I know there must be something there because the webview displays the authenticated page fine (you can't get there unless you're authorised + cookie).

How can I get a full list of the headers to make sure I'm getting all the headers I'm supposed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to my own question.

What I have in my code to return all headers is correct. Using `HTTPClient.getResponseHeaders()` is the correct method for iOS and `HTTPClient.getAllResponseHeaders()` for Android (no idea why there's two different ways - that could be a question for another day).

The reason I'm not seeing the cookie header is because of a bug in Titanium 1.7.5 (and still exists in 1.8.1). It's not forwarding on the cookie on a 302 redirect.

Jiras on the issues:

- https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4537
- https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-1322

Comment: Thank you.. so much. I was about to throw my laptop out the window, but this is a much better solution.